# Angular Testing: Spy a function that was executed on the initialize of a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to spy a function that was executed on the initialize of a controller, but the test always failed. 
I've been trying execute `$scope.$digest()` and this it's not working, However in the console, i see that the function have been called.

I can't figure out this, Someone can explain to me why this it's not working?

Codepen Example: 
http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/KzZNby

**Controller**

```
function Controller($stateParams, $scope){

  $scope.requestAuthorization = requestAuthorization;

  if ($stateParams.requestAuthorization === true) {
    console.log('$stateParams.requestAuthorization');
    $scope.requestAuthorization();
  }
  function requestAuthorization() {
    console.log('requestAuthorization()');
  }
}
```

**Testing**

```
describe('AppCtrl', function(){
     var AppCtrl, $rootScope, $scope, $stateParams;

    beforeEach(module('exampleApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$injector_, _$stateParams_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
        $stateParams.requestAuthorization = true;


        AppCtrl = $controller('AppCtrl',{
            $scope: $scope,
            $stateParams : $stateParams
        });

        spyOn($scope, 'requestAuthorization');          
    }));

     it('$stateParams.requestAuthorization should be defined', function() {             
        expect($stateParams.requestAuthorization).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('$scope.requestAuthorization should be defined', function() {
        expect($scope.requestAuthorization).toBeDefined();
    });

    // this test is not passing.. 
    it('should call requestAuthorization', function() {
                //$scope.$digest();
        expect($scope.requestAuthorization).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Comment: I believe you would have to initialize the controller in the test case itself, spyOn it before the initialization of the controller, then check the expected result after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test is failing because spy gets overridden by real function when controller initializes. One way to avoid this is monkey-patching `$scope` object with custom setter for `requestAuthorization` property, that could create spy when controller is trying to assign value to this property:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$injector_, _$stateParams_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var reqAuthSpy;
        Object.defineProperty($scope, 'requestAuthorization', {
            get: function() {return reqAuthSpy;},
            set: function(fn) {
             reqAuthSpy = jasmine.createSpy('reqAuthSpy');
            }
        });
        $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
        $stateParams.requestAuthorization = true;


        AppCtrl = $controller('AppCtrl',{
            $scope: $scope,
            $stateParams : $stateParams
        });

    }));
```